# Reload config file in Python

Tags: python, configparser

I'm using configparser and loading a config.ini file in my code. The code works in a loop, and I want to be able to edit the config parameters on the file, and the code to reload and update them after every iteration. Also, the variables are common, used by more submodules.

To achieve this, I tried to load the configfile and the variables in an init.py file, which I'm importing in every module. The config file reading and the variable declaration are in functions. In the main.py I call those functions after every loop, hoping it would update the data if the config.ini was modified, but it doesn't work. Tried reimporting the init.py module, but that doesn't help me either.

This works if it's just one file:

```py
import configparser as cfg

def load_config(configfile):
    cc = cfg.ConfigParser()
    cc.read(configfile)
    return cc

def load_variables(cc):
    return cc.getint('some section', 'some key')
    
configfile = './config.ini'
cf = load_config(configfile)
variable = load_variables(cf)

while True:
    do_stuff(variable)
    del cf
    cf = load_config(configfile)
    variable = load_variables(cf)
```

But if I try this (mockup edit of the above), the variables won't change values. I debugged to a point where I see, that the configparser object refreshes, but the variables aren't:

```
init.py:
def load_config
def load_variables
    
main.py
from init import *
while True:
   do stuff
   load_config
   load_variables
```

I guess I'm doing something fundamentally wrong... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I figured it out...

While it's possible to empty the config object, and reload every value in it, if I reload the variables from the config object IN the init.py, it doesn't matter I declare them as globals, they are globals in the scope of init.py, and with the from init.py import * statement, they are imported into the main.py mainspace.
I don't know if they are becoming immutable, or the load_variables only changes the values in the scope of the init.py (which isn't reloaded itself) but it causes this problem.

Solution: as I should've done it the first time: do not use from* import, just get the variables directly like a sane person: init.some_variable
I refactored like this, and now the load_variables function actually updates the values in main.py too.

TLDR: just an another example, if the experienced programmers tell you to not do something, you really shouldn't, like `from your_stupid_lib import *`